# Angular - Appearance outline label border

Tags: css, angular

Im having some problem with Angular 16 and Material.
As you can see, it adds a strange border-right at the end of label width.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                  <mat-label> as you see, the border is related to this label </mat-label>
                  <input  matInput  type="text" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="user_search.probe" name="probe">
</mat-form-field>
```

[image]

When the focus is on the input, Angular adds a strange width style that is not equals to the total width of the input.

[image]

Any of you had similar problem?